# Mirror Image and vampire charming

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, charmed

Is a mirror image effective against the vampire charm? Does the vampire have to target the right target with his/her gaze? Meaning that if he/she target an image the effect is null.

> xxx targets one humanoid it can see within 30 feet of it. If the
> target can see xxx, the target must succeed on a DC ?? Wisdom saving
> throw against this magic or be charmed...

Comment: I tagged this as dnd-5e as your rules text excerpt matches the 5e text. You always should tag the game systems, as the monsters, spells and classes work differently in different systems and editions. Let us know if this is not for 5e D&D

Comment: The answer is the same, but since vampire gaze isn't a spell I don't think this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mirror image only works against attacks

The spell says:

> Each time a creature targets you with **an attack** during the spell's duration, roll a d20 to determine whether the attack instead targets one of your duplicates.

The vamire's gaze is not an attack, as it does not involve an attack roll. *PHB*, p. 194

> If there’s ever any question whether something you’re doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you’re making an attack roll, you’re making an attack.

Since the gaze is not an attack, and *mirror image* only protects against attacks, *mirror image* does not work against the gaze.